# Fischer's Mutual Exclusion Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, real-time, mutual-exclusion

Two processes are trying to enter their critical sections, executing the same program:

```
while true do begin
  // Noncritical section.
  L: if not(id=0) then goto L;
  id := i; 
  pause(delay);
  if not(id=i) then goto L;
  // Inside critical section.
  id := 0; 
end
```

The constant i identifies the process (i.e., has the value 1 or 2), and id is a global variable, with value 0 initially. The statement pause(delay) delays the execution for delay time units. It is assumed that the assignment id := i; takes at most t time units.

It has been proved that for delay > t the algorithm is correct.

**I have two questions:**

1) Suppose both processes A and B pass the control at label L. Suppose that at this point A get always chosen by the scheduler until it enters in its critical section. Suppose that, while A is in it critical section, the scheduler dispatches process B; since it has already passed the control at label L it also can enter in its critical section. Where am i wrong?

2) Why if delay == t the algorithm isn't correct?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that process A and B reach the label L at times `t_A` and `t_B` respectively (`t_A < t_B`) but the difference between these times is smaller-equal than `t` (worst-case assignment time).  If it was larger than `t`, process B would stop at label L and wait until `id=0`.

As a result, process B will still see `id=0` and assign its ID as well. But process A is not aware about this assignment yet. The only way for process A to get informed about this assignment is to wait for some time and re-check the value of `id`.

This waiting time must be larger that `t`. Why?

Let's consider two edge cases here

-case 1: `t_A = t_B`, in other words, process A and B reached label L at the same time. They both see `id=0` and hence assign their IDs to it.

Let's assume that process A's assignment finishes in almost 0 time and process B's assignment finishes in worst-case time `t`. This means that process A has to delay more than `t` time, in order to see the process B's update to variable `id`. If delay is smaller-equal than `t`, the update will not be visible and they both will enter critical section. This is actually already sufficient for claiming that delay has to be larger than `t`.

-case 2: `t_B = t_A + t`, in other words, process A reaches label L, assigns its ID in worst-case time `t`, then after `t` time, process B reaches label L, checks `id=0` (because assignment of process A has not finished yet) and assigns its ID in worst-case time `t`. Again here, if process A's delay will be smaller-equal than `t`, it will not see the update of process B.

Comment: Is it assumed that every instruction that ends with ; it's atomic ? Then, the preemption can happen only between instructions? In fact i think this algo should also work in a single processor scenario.
Moreover, the check "if not(id=i)..." takes some time, so if delay==t, the algorithm should still work. Where am i wrong ?

Comment: @AleWereWolf surely `if not(id=i)` has a worst-case execution time as well, say `t0`. It still makes no difference except that the delay has to be larger than `t0 + t`. Regarding atomicity, in this algorithm atomicity doesn't seem to be required. Assigment can be preempted in the middle and the algorithm is still valid